# P&S Exc 3.4e, why does the double creation operator term vanish in the Hamiltonian of the free Majorana quantum field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, majorana-fermions

I'm attempting to solve Exc. 3.4e from Peskin and Schroeder, which is about Majorana Fermions. We are asked to diagonalize the Hamiltonian in terms of creation and anhiliation operators. Now I'm studying a solution by hong-Zhi Xianyu https://zzxianyu.files.wordpress.com/2017/01/peskin_problems.pdf, where I'm having trouble to show that the term with two creation operators vanishes. This term is given by:

\begin{align}
\Sigma_{a,b} a_a^\dagger(\boldsymbol{p})a_b^\dagger(-\boldsymbol{p})
\xi_a^\dagger (-(\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma})^\dagger(\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma})(\sqrt{\tilde{p}\cdot\sigma})(-i\sigma^2)
+\\
\frac{im}{2}(\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma})^\dagger \sigma^2 (\sqrt{\tilde{p}\cdot\sigma})^*
-\\ 
\frac{im}{2}(i\sigma^2)(\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma})^T\sigma^2(\sqrt{\tilde{p}\cdot\sigma})(-i\sigma^2))\xi_b^*.
\end{align}

Here $\sigma = (I, \sigma^1, \sigma^2, \sigma^3)$, $\sigma^2$ is the second Pauli matrix (not a square of the $\sigma$ mentioned earlier), $\bar{\sigma} = (I, -\sigma^1, -\sigma^2, -\sigma^3)$, $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ form an orthonormal basis for 2-component spinors (similar to what is used for the free solution of the Dirac equation).

Some helpful identities suposedly are
$$(p\cdot\sigma)^2 = (p\cdot\bar{\sigma})^2=E_p^2+\boldsymbol{p}^2,$$ $$(p\cdot\sigma)(p\cdot\bar{\sigma})=p^2=m^2,$$ $$\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}=\frac{1}{2}(p\cdot\bar{\sigma}-p\cdot\sigma).$$

Why does this term vanish?

**Edit** 2023-04-26 Added tilde on some $p$ terms, these where missing. I think the meaning of the tilde is as follows $\tilde{p} = (p_0,-p_1.-p_2,-p_3)$.
**Edit** 2023-04-26 (2) fixed several typos.

Answer (score 0):

Use $-\tilde{p}\cdot\sigma=p\cdot\bar\sigma$ and
$$\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}\ \mathbf{p}\cdot\pmb{\sigma}\sqrt{p\cdot\bar\sigma}=m\ (\mathbf{p}\cdot\pmb{\sigma}). $$

Second and third term can be transformed in the same way, by using your third formula and $(\sigma_\mu)^*=\sigma_2\bar\sigma\sigma_2$. Let's derive a similar formula for transposition and organize the equation.

Comment: For the first one I get $-p\cdot\sigma = -p_0\sigma_0 +\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ and $p\cdot\bar{\sigma} = p_0\sigma_0+\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ so how are they equal? (Note I'm using the convention that $a\cdot b = a_0b_0 -a_1b_1 - a_2b_2-a_3b_3$. Also the formula $\sqrt{p\cdot\bar{\sigma}}\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}\sqrt{p\cdot{\sigma}}$ doesn't occur directly in the expression, where can I use that?

Comment: I have corrected the error. Let's transform your first term closer to the equation I showed you. Furthermore, if you transform the second and third terms using the formula in my answer, you can show that these terms cancel.